# Favourite button change when i scroll down and up in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have one bookCollectionview in that i have one favourite button. problem is when i click on button is make favourite but when i scroll down and up again it will deselected. my api working fine. when refresh api its become selected. only issue first time.

**collectionview.swift**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! AllBooksCollectionViewCell

    let ad: Int? = Int(BookId[indexPath.item])

    cell.FavouritButton.tag = ad!

    if  BookFlag[indexPath.row] == "false" {
        cell.flag = 0
        cell.FavouritButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"icons8-sta-30.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.FavouritButton.isSelected = true
    } else {
        cell.flag = 1
        cell.FavouritButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"icons8-star-filled-30.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.FavouritButton.isSelected = false
    }
    if let url = NSURL(string: BookImageUrl[indexPath.row])
    {
        cell.CellImage.setUrl(url as URL)
    }

    cell.BookExtensionLabel.text = BookFileExtension[indexPath.row]
    cell.BookTitleTextView.text = BookTitle[indexPath.row]
    indicator.stopAnimating()
    BookCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    return cell
}
```

**CollectionViewCell.swift**

```
@IBOutlet weak var FavouritButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func FavouritButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.flag == 0
        {
            let image1 = UIImage(named: "icons8-star-filled-30.png") as UIImage!
            self.FavouritButton.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
            self.flag = 1
            print(self.flag)
            self.webService(Action: "set_favourite_book", BookId: sender.tag)
            sender.isSelected = false

            // BookCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
        else
        {
            let image1 = UIImage(named: "icons8-sta-30.png") as UIImage!
            self.FavouritButton.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
            self.flag = 0
            self.webService(Action: "set_favourite_book", BookId: sender.tag)
            print(self.flag)
            sender.isSelected = true
            //  BookCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a very common mistake. You are changing a value in the view (the cell) but you don't update the model (data source array) accordingly. You need to change the value also in the item `BookFlag[indexPath.row]` in the controller. By the way, why do you use the string `"false"` rather than `Bool` `false`. And please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: how can i change value of BookFlag[indexPath.row] in my cell .

Comment: 1. i have to take string coz of api 2. ad is that im converting string to integer coz in api i have to send book id

Comment: The easiest way is a callback closure

Comment: @vadian sorry i didnt understand  callback closure?

Comment: I wrote an answer. Please learn to understand patterns like callback closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very common mistake. You are changing a value in the view (the cell) but you don't update the model (data source array) accordingly. You need to change the value also in the item `BookFlag[indexPath.row]` in the controller.

---

In the cell add a closure variable and call it in the branches of the `IBAction`

```
class AllBooksCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var FavouritButton: UIButton!

    var callback : ((String) -> ())?
    var flag = 0

    @IBAction func FavouritButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.flag == 0
            {
                let image1 = UIImage(named: "icons8-star-filled-30.png") as UIImage!
                self.FavouritButton.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
                self.flag = 1
                print(self.flag)
                self.webService(Action: "set_favourite_book", BookId: sender.tag)
                sender.isSelected = false
                self.callback?("true")
            }
            else
            {
                let image1 = UIImage(named: "icons8-sta-30.png") as UIImage!
                self.FavouritButton.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
                self.flag = 0
                self.webService(Action: "set_favourite_book", BookId: sender.tag)
                print(self.flag)
                sender.isSelected = true
                self.callback?("false")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `cellForItemAt` add the callback closure

```
...
   } else {
        cell.flag = 1
        cell.FavouritButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"icons8-star-filled-30.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.FavouritButton.isSelected = false
    }

    cell.callback = { [unowned self] flag in
        self.BookFlag[indexPath.row] = flag
    }

    if let url = NSURL(string: BookImageUrl[indexPath.row])
    {
        cell.CellImage.setUrl(url as URL)
    }
...
```

**Note:** For data consistency you should use a `Bool` for the flag rather then a `String` in the controller and an `Int` in the cell. And – once again – *please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter.*